# D and pseudo-terminals

Tags: d, expect, pty

Does D have built in support for pseudo-terminals via the Phobos runtime libraries ?...I'm assuming there isn't since ptys are highly platform specific. Are there other third party alternatives ?  Ultimately, I'd like to implement an Expect-like library for D if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "support for pseudo-terminals via the Phobos runtime" you mean some higher level abstraction on top of the pseudo-terminals supported by the underlying operating-system, then I must say I have never seen such a thing. Like C++, D can directly call C functions, so I believe writing an expect-like application in D should not be difficult if you already did something similar in C or C++.

On Linux people typically call `openpty(3)`, `forkpty(3)` or `login_tty(3)` functions. I do not know about other systems.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize how easy it was to interface to the C libraries. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Yep, the D runtime uses C functions quite a lot. Also take a look at the Deimos organisation on GitHub - https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos . You will find lots of various bindings to C libraries there.